# regex strsplit expression in R so it only applies once to the first occurrence of a specific character in each string?

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I have a list filled with strings:
`string<- c("SPG_L_subgenual_ACC_R", "SPG_R_MTG_L_pole", "MTG_L_pole_CerebellumGM_L")`

I need to split the strings so they appear like:

`"SPG_L", "subgenual_ACC_R", "SPG_R", "MTG_L_pole", "MTG_L_pole", "CerebellumGM_L"`

I tried using the following regex expression to split the strings:

`str_split(string,'(?<=[[RL]|pole])_')`

But this leads to:

`"SPG_L", "subgenual" "ACC_R", "SPG_R", "MTG_L", "pole", "MTG_L", "pole", "CerebellumGM_L"`

How do I edit the regex expression so it splits each string element at the "_" after the first occurrence of "R", "L" unless the first occurrence of "R" or "L" is followed by "pole", then it splits the string element after the first occurrence of "pole" and only splits each string element once?

Comment: Wouldn't the first occurrence of "R", "L", or "pole" in `MTG_L_pole_CerebellumGM_L` split it into `MTG_L` and `pole_CerebellumGM_L`

Comment: You are right. I need to split the string after the first occurrence of "R" or "L" unless the first occurrence of "R" or "L" is followed by "pole", then I need to split it at the "_" after the first occurrence of "pole".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a *matching* approach using

```
^(.*?[RL](?:_pole)?)_(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Osenzd/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?[RL](?:_pole)?)` - Group 1:

  - `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
  - `[RL](?:_pole)?` -  `R` or `L` optionally followed with `_pole`
- `_` - an underscore
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible

See [the R demo](https://rextester.com/WJUM36973):

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("SPG_L_subgenual_ACC_R", "SPG_R_MTG_L_pole", "MTG_L_pole_CerebellumGM_L", "SFG_pole_R_IFG_triangularis_L", "SFG_pole_R_IFG_opercularis_L" )

res <- str_match_all(x, "^(.*?[RL](?:_pole)?)_(.*)")
lapply(res, function(x) x[-1])
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "SPG_L"           "subgenual_ACC_R"

[[2]]
[1] "SPG_R"      "MTG_L_pole"

[[3]]
[1] "MTG_L_pole"     "CerebellumGM_L"

[[4]]
[1] "SFG_pole_R"         "IFG_triangularis_L"

[[5]]
[1] "SFG_pole_R"        "IFG_opercularis_L"
```

Comment: This is an efficient approach. I realized that there are some cases in my dataset where "pole" occurs before the first occurrence of "R" or "L"- see this list    
```string<- c("SPG_L_subgenual_ACC_R", "SPG_R_MTG_L_pole", "MTG_L_pole_CerebellumGM_L", "SFG_pole_R_IFG_triangularis_L", "SFG_pole_R_IFG_opercularis_L" )```  How would you edit the matching regex expression so instances where "pole" comes before "R" or "L", the string is split on the underscore after the "R" or "L"?

Comment: So ```"SFG_pole_R_IFG_triangularis_L"``` would become ```"SFG_pole_R", "IFG_triangularis_L"``` and ```"SFG_pole_R_IFG_opercularis_L"``` would become ```"SFG_pole_R", "IFG_opercularis_L" ```

Answer (score 0):

```
split_again = function(x){
  if(length(x) > 1){
    return(x)
  }
  else{
    str_split(
      string = x,
      pattern = '(?<=[R|L])_', 
      n = 2)
  }
}
str_split(
  string = string,
  pattern = '(?<=pole)_', 
  n = 2) %>% 
  lapply(split_again) %>% 
  unlist()
```

Comment: Hi svenhalvorson, the function you wrote works great! However, I have a few instances where "pole" occurs before the first occurrence of "R" or "L" "SFG_pole_R_IFG_opercularis_L" and "SFG_pole_R_IFG_triangularis_L" and I need to split these at "SFG_pole_R" , "IFG_opercularis_L",  "SFG_pole_R", and "IFG_triangularis_L". How would you adjust the function to cases where "pole" is before the first occurrence of "R" and "L"

Comment: @nagpal826 change the first `str_split`'s pattern to `'(?<=pole?(_[R|L]))_'`? Think that will work

Comment: I'm not sure what that did, but it turned this string ```string<- c("SPG_L_subgenual_ACC_R", "SPG_R_MTG_L_pole", "MTG_L_pole_CerebellumGM_L", "SFG_pole_R_IFG_triangularis_L", "SFG_pole_R_IFG_opercularis_L" ) ``` into ```[1] "SPG_L_subgenual_ACC_R" "SPG_R_MTG_L_pole"      "MTG_L_pole"            "CerebellumGM_L"       
[5] "SFG_pole"              "R_IFG_triangularis_L"  "SFG_pole"              "R_IFG_opercularis_L" ```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `sub` then `strsplit` as shown:

```
strsplit(sub("^.*?[LR](?:_pole)?\\K_",":",string,perl=TRUE),":")
[[1]]
[1] "SPG_L"           "subgenual_ACC_R"

[[2]]
[1] "SPG_R"      "MTG_L_pole"

[[3]]
[1] "MTG_L_pole"     "CerebellumGM_L"
```